# Do Shillelagh and Sacred Weapon stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I am playing a level six warlock/paladin. I took Pact of Tome and picked up *shillelagh*, and I took Oath of Devotion for *sacred weapon*.

If I am understanding this correctly, with my charisma of 20 my attack roll gets +3+5+5 for a +13 total bonus, and my damage roll gets +5. The problem is that I have no idea if these abilities' bonuses stack like that or not. Do they?

Answer (score 22):

Yes, *shillelagh* and Sacred Weapon will stack. Although technically speaking, it's not *stacking* as such, because they actually do entirely different things.

*Shillelagh* replaces Strength with your spellcasting ability (in your case, Charisma):

> For the duration, you can
>   use your spellcasting ability instead of Strength for
>   the attack and damage rolls of melee attacks using
>   that weapon, and the weapon's damage die becomes
>   a d8.

Then Sacred Weapon adds a bonus equal to your Charisma:

> For 1 minute, you add
>   your Charisma modifier to attack rolls made with that
>   weapon (with a minimum bonus of +1).

If, for example, they both replaced Strength with Charisma, they wouldn't stack. If they both allowed you to add Charisma as a bonus, then depending on the wording they *might* not stack. However, since one is replacing Strength as your ability modifier for the attack, and one is adding a bonus, there's no overlap between them and they will definitely stack.

Comment: This combo also spends one charge of Channel Divinity (which you get once per short rest) and a spell slot (of which neither the Paladin nor the Warlock have many). Still worth it for an important fight, but usually a careful player would choose to ration these effects.

Comment: @DaFluid Shillelagh is a cantrip, so no spell slot involved. But yeah, Channel Divinity means you can't do this too much.